# htaccess rewrite condition 404 all querystring only on index page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

i was trying to protect the main page because on google console my report on a querystring is visible like this example:

```
https://example.com/?s=something.g
```

i would like to 404 all querystring only on the main page "example.com/" but any other like the javascripts/css files, folders and wp-admin can use querystrings

this is not allowed (only on main page):

```
https://example.com/?anything=something
https://example.com/?anythingnew=something&anotherone=something
https://example.com/index.php?anything=something
```

but these urls should be allowed (all other should be good):

```
https://example.com/something.js?anything=something
https://example.com/folder/?anything=something
https://example.com/folder/anotherfolder/anyfile.php?anything=something
```

i was trying to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\?
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=404,L]
```

it appears that all querystrings as disallowed including the files and folders inside.

i also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=404,L]
```

same thing, nothing worked, the rule should only be in the main page. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You were not far from the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?$ - [R=404,L]
```

#### Explained

1. The ***RewriteRule*** will take the path (without the query string)
   as input. So, if you want to apply this rule only for the homepage
   (with or without `index.php`) then you have to write a regular
   expression such as `^(?:index\.php)?$` :

   - `^` matches the beginning of the string, meaning *"it should
     start with"* instead of just *"it should contain"*.
   - `$` matches the end of the string, meaning
     *"it should finish with"*.
   - `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. If you put `()` then it's a
     capturing group, which will generate a variable called `$1`.
     But we don't need to capture this part to put it back in the new
     rewritten URL as we can just put `-` to say *"nothing to change"*
     and generate the 404 error. Putting the question mark behind this
     group means that it can be present or not. I've put `index\.php`
     inside it to say that we can have it or not in the URL. The dot
     has to be escaped because `.` means *"any char"* in a regular
     expression pattern.

   You might see someone write also `^/?(?:index\.php)?$` to say that
   it could be with or without the leading slash. But normally
   *Apache* will always strip this leading slash before using it in
   the *RewriteRule* test. So there's no reason to put it as this test
   will use a few CPU cycles for nothing.
2. The ***RewriteCond*** is only run if we enter the *RewriteRule*.
   Here, we want to test if the query string is empty or not. This can
   easily be done by matching any char one or several times with `.+`.
   It would work with or without the `^` and `$` around. I prefer
   putting them to show that the full query string must not be empty.